# ios memory leak hunting

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

I work on an application that comprises several minigames. One of these minigames obviously leaks memory. This minigame, in turn, is not that "mini". It includes a dozen of sources. And frankly speaking, they are awful.

How do I find memory leak? My idea is to set some "begin hunt" marker when the minigame starts and output all objects that were allocated since marker set and not freed at the moment when minigame finishes. Do iOS debug facilities allow it?

Comment: have you thought of running it under Instruments, or through the Static Analyser?

Comment: Have you tried the "standard" leak detection method? http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial

Comment: Yes. Static Analyzer generates a plenty of "potential leak" warnings, and I checked some of them: really they are not leaks. Instruments informed me about a couple of 64-byte leaks (without detailed info), but really this minigame leaks ~ 20Mb (as I can see in Activity Monitor). That's why I want to see a full list of allocatons occured after minigame has started.